# Chromium has graphics glitches when hardware acceleration is enabled

Tags: 22.04, chromium, amdgpu, hardware-acceleration

I have issues with my chromium when i activate Hardware acceleration.
So looks my `chrome://gpu` when i enable hardware acceleration.
[image]
And all other windows and tabs of Chromium.
I need to disable acceleration in `Settings -> System -> Use hardware acceleration when available`

I already tried to use flags like:

```
--use-cmd-decoder=validating
--use-gl=desktop
```

But they are not solving glitches.

How can i enable acceleration without extra graphic glitches?

**UPD 2023.04.29**
I have tested my system with LiveUSB Mate 22.04 and `amdgpu-pro` drivers.
Hardware acceleration works without any bugs.
Here is screenshot:
[image]

How can i narrow down my glitches with Hardware acceleration and fix it?

Specs:

- Ubuntu mate 22.04 64 bit with latest patches upgraded from 20.04.
- Chromium in Snap from Ubuntu repos.
- GPU Radeon 5500XT with latest `amdgpu-pro` drivers.

Comment: Was it glitching before you installed the unnecessary proprietary overlay?

Comment: @ChanganAuto What unnecessary proprietary overlay? It is usual Chromium that is distributed by Canonical in their snaps. Only extra extensions are uBlock and Vimium.

Comment: Yup. It does. It also causes crashes on some devices.  Disable it. It doesn't work and last I knew they had no plans on making it work. See [here](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/10/hardware-acceleration-chrome-linux). I have no idea why they include it in the Linux version, and even less of an idea as to why it is enabled by default.

Comment: By unnecessary proprietary overlay I'm referring to `amdgpu-pro`. Ubuntu comes with drivers for AMD graphics already.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I need it for working Vulkan.

Comment: @KGIII It has worked in 20.04 and it works on my Intel based Laptop. So i would like to enable it.

Comment: *I need it for working Vulkan*. No, you don't, `amdgpu` supports Vulkan. And you still haven't answered my initial question.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I need it. Simple amdpu is not working with some of my apps.
Before upgrade to 22.04 i have used 20.04 with same hardware, driver and working acceleration.

Comment: I believe you'll find that no, it's not 'working' on those devices,  it is *just not causing problems* on those devices. See the link I posted.

Comment: No, you absolutely DON'T need it and this is the end of the discussion we shouldn't even be having as comments aren't meant for that. **You still haven't answered the question nor stated that is unanswerable because system was release upgraded with `amdgpu-pro` already installed** Now, that can be a problem because AMD publishes 2 different versions for 20.04 and 22.04. So, you should perhaps reinstall it using the correct version. And indeed as @KGIII mentioned, it isn't working on those devices, it is just not causing problems.

Comment: **`chromium-dev` from the PPA** with some extra few steps on top of those required for uninstalling the snap version and preventing it's automatic reinstallation instead of the .deb version, **can use hardware acceleration, albeit experimental**. And, of course, you're welcome to ask specific questions about those "apps of yours" that mysteriously don't work with the official open-source AMD driver `amdgpu`, I think you're in for a surprise.

Comment: FYI: https://github.com/GPUOpen-Drivers/AMDVLK Quoting (my bold): *The AMD Open Source Driver for Vulkan is designed to support following distros and versions **on both the AMDGPU upstream driver stack** and the AMDGPU Pro driver stack.*